# C++ strings and arrays (very simple)

Tags: c++

I am having an extremely difficult time trying to solve this. I would like to know how can I store a string input into an array in C++? I would like the array to be of size 12 because the inputs are going to be binary numbers, so for example this is what I want:

The input is going to be a binary number, 10100 for example, and I want to store that binary number into an array so that the array will look like this --> `[1][0][1][0][0]`. I want to store in an array any binary number, or, any number of 0's and 1's that the user gives.

Comment: Why size 12?  That number doesn't have any notable special relationship with binary.

Comment: While we're happy to answer beginner questions here, it's important to be a bit more specific - if we answered every vague question ('How do arrays work?') with a detailed tutorial we'd be here all day. Try reading some C++ tutorials and see what you can cobble together. When you get stuck somewhere specific, feel free to ask a specific question then.

Comment: because 12 would be the size of the array to store any binary number with 12 or less 0's and 1's

Comment: +1 for the lol.  Welcome to the tautology club ;-)

Comment: Junior89, please clarify exactly what you want. I don't think you know.

Comment: @Code Monkey I just want to store an input given by a user into an array, so that when I check array[1] if its a 1 C1++, elseif its a 0 C0++, then I go on to check array[2], and etc.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is to use the c_str() function of c++ string.  This will create a null terminated array of characters that's the same as your original string (you can just ignore the last byte)

so if you have the string myString

```
char * byteArray = myString.c_str()
```

will produce the above array

keep in mind that you can also just reference strings using []

```
string myString = "1101"
//option 1
char firstBit = myString[0];
//option 2
const char * primitiveArray = myString.c_str();
char firstBitOther = primitiveArray[0];
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your answer, but I do not know how to do that, I am kind of new to this. Could you possibly show me an example code?

Comment: @Junior89 How does the given example code not do what you want already?

Comment: ``string::c_str()`` returns a `const char*`, not a `char *`. This code won't compile.

Comment: @you set mystring to equal a binary, I want to input a binary number myself and from there I want the program to store the input binary number into an array of size 12. And with your code I get an error say " invalid conversion from `const char*' to `char*' "